# Why IntValidator's bottom not working in QT?

Tags: qt, qml

Now i am using a IntValidator in a TextInput with a bottom value greater than 0, just like: 
`validator: IntValidator{bottom: 20; top: 100;}`
But i still can input a unwanted value like 10 and the input text won't clear after lose focus.
I don't know why? Anyone can help me.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntValidator tries to validate your input every time you type a character and returns 3 possible states: Invalid, Intermediate, Acceptable.

Imagine a scenario where you set your bottom value to 20 and your top value to 1000.
Now you want to type 100, but the IntValidator would report Invalid for 1, 10 because these values are lower than 20, thus it would not let you enter any of these, this is why it returns Intermediate.

You can see what is going on in Qt's source:

```
QValidator::State QIntValidator::validate(QString & input, int&) const
{
    QByteArray buff;
    if (!locale().d->m_data->validateChars(input, QLocaleData::IntegerMode, &buff, -1,
                                           locale().numberOptions())) {
        return Invalid;
    }
    if (buff.isEmpty())
        return Intermediate;
    const bool startsWithMinus(buff[0] == '-');
    if (b >= 0 && startsWithMinus)
        return Invalid;
    const bool startsWithPlus(buff[0] == '+');
    if (t < 0 && startsWithPlus)
        return Invalid;
    if (buff.size() == 1 && (startsWithPlus || startsWithMinus))
        return Intermediate;
    bool ok;
    qlonglong entered = QLocaleData::bytearrayToLongLong(buff.constData(), 10, &ok);
    if (!ok)
        return Invalid;
    if (entered >= b && entered <= t) {
        locale().toInt(input, &ok);
        return ok ? Acceptable : Intermediate;
    }
    if (entered >= 0) {
        // the -entered < b condition is necessary to allow people to type
        // the minus last (e.g. for right-to-left languages)
        // The buffLength > tLength condition validates values consisting
        // of a number of digits equal to or less than the max value as intermediate.
        int buffLength = buff.size();
        if (startsWithPlus)
            buffLength--;
        const int tLength = t != 0 ? static_cast<int>(std::log10(qAbs(t))) + 1 : 1;
        return (entered > t && -entered < b && buffLength > tLength) ? Invalid : Intermediate;
    } else {
        return (entered < b) ? Invalid : Intermediate;
    }
}
```

If you want to reach your goal validating an integer within a range, better to let the user type anything except alphabetical and special characters (-+ should be allowed as first char) using a RegExpValidator and subscribe to the editingFinished and activeFocusChanged signals so when the user pressed enter or leaves the TextInput field you can validate the input value yourself and even update it to be in the desired range.