# how to allow only certain numbers to be entered inside textField in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, textfield

I have a TextField as shown in the code i have to mkae sure the user enters only numbers between 100-5000.

```
TextField{
                id:custom_entry
                objectName: "custom_entry"
                width: 200
                placeholderText: "Enter 100ms - 5000ms"
                validator: IntValidator {bottom: 100; top: 5000;}
            }
```

I have tried with the validator with this i can enter any 4 digit number even 9999, how do i limit this in QML.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463377/why-intvalidators-bottom-not-working-in-qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RegularExpressionValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-regularexpressionvalidator.html) like :

```
    TextField{
        validator: RegularExpressionValidator{
            regularExpression: /^[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-4][0-9]{3}|5000/
        }
    }
```

As long as the user should be able to enter a number like **999**, then the `TextField` will also allow entering a number like **99**. You can always check the readonly propery [`acceptableInput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#acceptableInput-prop) of `TextField` to make sure that the entered value is in range.